# Allow filter by all attributes even if product does not exist in current category

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation

More of a conceptual questions really.

Is there anyway to display and allow filter by all available attributes in every category. For example; in the shoes category, show and allow filter by the 't-shirt' attribute, even though no 't-shirt' products exist in shoes category.

I presume this is not possible unless all products existed in all categories? Which would presumably be an issue for SEO anyway?

I've had a client ask this question and wanted to make sure it wasn't possible before I tell them as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open the attribute and set "Used in Layered Navigation" to "Filterable (no results)"

Comment: Thanks for response Amasty - and what does that do please?

Comment: It always shows all available filter options. Even if some option has zero products associated.